# Add a field in all existing documents and constant value for all the documents

Tags: mongodb

Want to add a field `NO_5` in all existing documents in a collection in mongodb and constant value Test for all the documents in that collection.

```
var i = 1
db.WebUser.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    db.WebUser.update(
       { "_id": doc._id },
       { "$set": { NO_5 : " Test"  }
   );
   i++;
})
```

Tried the above one, but no use.

Answer (score 1):

```
db.WebUser.updateMany({}, {"$set": {"NO_5":"Test"}, o, function(err, result) {
// see result
});
```

Comment: I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: I think there is no need for that.